# Expected '(end)' and instead saw '}'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jslint to help fix some javascript and it returned with at the end of this script.

```
$("ul").wrap("<p class='content'></p>");
$("hr.x-gap").css("border-top","");
}
```

I have been trying to fix it, but I have been unable to find the solution.

Comment: Delete the `}`...

Comment: we need to see some more code to give you a useful answer.

Comment: If you're going to use SO to learn a programming language, you're going to have a bad day. Get a good book on javascript and read it. Maybe get two. This coming from a guy who bought two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like just removing the curly brace would fix your issue. We'd need to see more code to be sure that's your problem however.

Comment: Thank you that worked! There was more code but the issue was isolated to that part of it. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

That issue will be fixed by deleting the `}` at the end of your code. However, when I try it in Jslint, many more errors pop up. I am not sure if this is a complete code segment, or part of something else you are writing. If this is supposed to be a standalone segment of code, then you did something wrong.

Comment: Thank you! There is more code but that was where the issue was.

Comment: No problem man. Make sure you accept an answer, whether it be mine or Nick Abbott's.